# Apps or cheap device to count the number of punches thrown on a heavy bag (but not necessarily the force, or the type of punches)

Tags: boxing, punching

I'm looking to buy a device or an app or install an app on my phone that'll count the number of punches I'm throwing in a certain interval on the heavy punching bag. I'm not trying to spend a lot of money, so this means I'm not looking to measure the force or the type of punches etc; just some device/app that will help me improve my speed by telling me how many punches I'm throwing in a certain interval. I don't think it should be that expensive, since it can count the number of punches by listening to the sound that corresponds to punches (provided I'm the only one punching the bag, otherwise it might be misguided...).

I'm based in Europe, but looking for European or global recommendations that are below 50€ for now. Of course, you can mention more expensive ones too, and I may buy them later.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't used it, but https://apps.apple.com/us/app/exercise-sound-counter/id1510585763?

Oh, are you restricted to Apple or Android? For Android, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keuwl.clapcounter&hl=en_US&gl=US?

Comment: FWIW, I tried the latter one out with a punchable bit of wall (it's padded) and the count seemed accurate, although it probably helped that there wasn't a lot of extraneous noise from the environment, and I wasn't grunting with the strikes.

Comment: I have an app in my brain that I use to count stuff like this. :)

Comment: Saw this on amazon:  https://www.amazon.com/UFC-Tracker-Sensitive-Kickboxing-Taekwondo/dp/B07FFG5TMT

Comment: And this: https://shop.hykso.com/

Comment: @MacacoBranco: thanks! Downloaded the Clap Counter app, and I'll test it out tomorrow or so. But before that, what's the Hz threshold should I set there? Put another way, what's the audio frequency of a decent punch to a heavy punching bag? Thanks again!

Comment: @SteveWeigand Thanks for the links, I'll check them out! As for counting with my head, when I'm into punching, I barely even try to count them in my head - but I think I've an estimate. I'm a beginner, and when I hit the bag not with much power but with max frequency, I think for the first 15-20 seconds or so, I can do two punches in one second, then for the next 15-20 seconds, one punch or 1.5 punch/second. After 40-45 second mark, it starts to get pretty hard for me...

Comment: @Mathmath Yeah, there are multiple ways of training for punching. There's speed, power, stamina / timed punching, combinations, body movement + combos, moving focus mitt, etc. Speed isn't something to focus on until you have proper form and can repeat it correctly and reliably with power.

Comment: In fairness, counting in your head's not always an option. Nor apps which use sound. We very often have a row of students and several assistants counting their punches. It's exceedingly difficult to count punches and offer encouragement at the same time, while also ignoring other Dans who are counting aloud!